# How to fix styles in safari browser?

Tags: html, css, sass, safari

I'm struggling with a problem with CSS styles in safari in all other browsers it works fine, can you please help me or tell how can I fix this?

**styles for phone:**

```
.link-g
  width: 100%
  color: $white
  font-family: Inter
  font-size: $m16
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: 400
  line-height: 146%
  text-decoration: none
  margin-top: 0
```

### My Footer with phone:

```
<div className="contact-group">
        <FontAwesomeIcon className="icon" icon={faPhone} />
        <a className="link-g" href="tel:+1 (312) 972-3890">
          +1 (312) 972-3890
        </a>
      </div>
```

### My address:

```
 <div className="contact-link-container mt32">
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLocationDot} className="fa-icon" />
                  <a href="" className="contact-link">
                    5516 N Major Ave Chicago IL 60630{" "}
                  </a>
                </div>
```

**styles for address:**

```
.contact-link
  color: $orange
  text-align: right
  font-family: Inter
  font-size: clamp(10px,1.0416vw,40px)
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: 400
  line-height: normal
  margin-left: $m8
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like https://webhint.io/ to check compatibility?

Comment: We need a [mcve]. Please see ask, and explain what the actual issue is since we have no idea. See [ask]

Comment: Problem with styles only in safari, as you can see on the screenshots it looks like this, in all other web browsers it works fine, so I'm wondering if there is any approach to fix this?

Comment: We can't troubleshoot screenshots. We need a **[mcve]**

Comment: I've provided a peace of code, I can't provide the whole component, because it will be too big, I just have error with 13-inch mac with these 2 elements